# Can I turn off the screen with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, display, screen

One of the first customizations I make in Windows is to install WinBubble, an awesome piece of software that lets me add an option the the right-click menu of the desktop: 'Turn Off Monitor.' It's really quite awesome.

Now that I'm using Macs more and more, I want to know how to do this on a Mac. But instead of using the mouse (yes, I'm a keyboard guy), I want to use the keyboard.

Is it possible for me to turn off the screen with a keyboard shortcut? I'm thinking AppleScript - but something simpler is definitely better.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Control+Shift+Power](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201236) For current Mac keyboard layouts. Control+Shift+Eject works for older keyboard layouts that still include the Eject key.

[This page](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/force-sleep-display-2010-2011) explains some alternate solutions as well.

Also, if you have "Require password after sleep or screen saver begins" set to immediately in **System Preferences** -> **Security & Privacy**, it will ask you for your password after doing this.

Comment: it's a photo finish!

Comment: Wow. Two answers, 11 seconds apart. I'll have to give this one to you. May I ask where you found this? I looked in Apple's record of keyboard shortcuts and found nada. I can't give you the answer for 11 minutes, though.

Comment: Here's an Apple article with these shortcuts- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2448 I think I found that one out by accident, though.

Comment: Found mine on Mac OS X Hints.

Comment: This _does not work_ for new macs that lack an eject key. Not sure what does, just pointing out that some macs can't do this operation out of the box.

Comment: @bmike this page explains some solutions for that http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/force-sleep-display-2010-2011

Comment: Woah - points here for summarizing and showing me I can put a modifier key on hot corners! FTFW! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47018/replacing-shortcuts-that-use-the-eject-key-on-macbook-air-lacking-such-a-physica

Comment: Hadn't even seen your question yet! :)

Comment: Just for the record, I don't believe this prevents your computer from going to sleep (eventually). You need to do an extra step for that: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120639/how-can-i-stop-my-macbook-pro-from-automatically-sleeping-when-i-lock-the-screen

Answer (score 8):

Yes - shift-ctrl-eject is the keyboard shortcut for this.