# How can I stop my MacBook Pro from automatically sleeping when I lock the screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, sleep-wake, screensaver

Whenever I lock my screen (via either the lock icon -> Lock screen or by using the Control+shift+eject key combination), my screen immediately turns off (not showing the screen saver), and the system seems to sleep. 
This is inconvenient because it disconnects me from the network, causing Jabber to go offline / ssh connections to die.

I am constantly connected to AC, and am using the following Energy Saver->Power Adapter options:

- Turn display off after: Never
- Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off
- Wake for Wi-Fi access

I have a 'late 2013' MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.1.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution that works for my needs: As it turns out, I should not lock the screen, but instead start the screensaver, and require the screensaver to immediately require a password.

I created a 'Start Screensaver' service with Automator, and then selected a keyboard shortcut for that service under Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Services.

Comment: Could you post your Automator script?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have the script, but this might help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135728/using-applescript-to-lock-screen

Answer (score 42):

Had the same problem in my Macbook(15") pro running **10.9.4**.

I wanted my Mac to be locked while I was away (so configured hot corners) but at the same time did not want it to sleep (irrespective of whether it is connected to power or not) so that my wifi will be "ON" always for my jabber & mails. So here's what I did to prevent Mac from sleeping:

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Run `sudo pmset -a sleep 0`

Explanation of the command:

- `pmset` command is to manipulate power management settings.
- `-a` specifies that the setting applies for all conditions (power & battery)
- `sleep` configure system sleep timer
- `0` to disable

Check out `man pmset` for more information.

Comment: How to turn it back on?

Comment: sudo pmset -a sleep 30 # will configure machine to sleep after 30 minutes

Comment: `pmset -g` will list current settings, but you can't say `pmset -g sleep` to just show what sleep is set to

Comment: Mine is already set to `sleep 0`, and it went to sleep anyway, while plugged in.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is in your post. **Just uncheck "Wake for Wifi Access" in the System Preferences under Energy Saver, Power Adapter.**

When it's checked, it means that your computer disconnects from the network when you're computer's not awake.

Comment: Really? Is this documented somewhere? The logic of the phrase "Wake for WiFi Access" suggests just that the checkbox should only affect waking behavior, not sleeping behavior.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

Use either [caffeinate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) or something like [wimoweh](http://www.serialangels.co.uk/index.php/wimoweh/)

Comment: So I need a third party app that prevents the mac from sleeping? I can't just disable 'sleep on lock' somehow?

Comment: caffeinate is part of the system but it's a command line tool.
I don't think there's a preference that will disable sleep completely. I will personally leave my macbook go to sleep and use [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) to circumvent the ssh disconnection problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Mac Book Pro running 10.9.5.  To keep it from sleeping when I locked the screen, I changed the Energy Saver settings for Power Adapter, I checked "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off" and I unchecked "Wake for network access".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [InsomniaX](https://github.com/semaja2/InsomniaX) for that.

With that, you can prevent your mac from sleeping, wether it's idle sleep or even when you close the lid.

Comment: Please summarize as the link might die in the future.

Comment: +1 the only one with decent settings for everything and it works on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

I went to **System Preferences** > **Energy Saver** and unchecked **Enabled Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter**.

Answer (score 0):

Install SmartSleep(from Apple Store) with Insomnia plugin and your problem should be solved. You can even play music with your lid closed with no problems.